# check if a date is null from within a lambda expression and use an alternative date only if it is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda, conditional-operator

I have some code to search for records created between two input dates (from and to) based upon the `createdDate`, however we have just imported some old  data and not all of the records have a `createdDate` which means that some records are not returned.  My idea is that when there is no `createdDate`, I use the `plannedStartDate` instead.  This is my original code:

```
mainTables = mainTables.Where(d => 
   d.n.CreatedDate >= AdminSearchVm.AdminSearch.SubmittedFrom &&
   d.n.CreatedDate <= AdminSearchVm.AdminSearch.SubmittedTo);
```

but I would like to do something like this:

```
mainTables = mainTables.Where(d => 
    d.n.CreatedDate == null ? d.n.PlannedStartDate :
    d.n.CreatedDate >= 
           AdminSearchVm.AdminSearch.SubmittedFrom && d.n.CreatedDate == null ? 
           d.n.PlannedStartDate : 
           d.n.CreatedDate <= AdminSearchVm.AdminSearch.SubmittedTo);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use this approach:

```
mainTables = mainTables
    .Select(t => new { Table = t, Date = (t.n.CreatedDate ?? t.n.PlannedStartDate) })
    .Where(x => x.Date >= AdminSearchVm.AdminSearch.SubmittedFrom && x.Date <= AdminSearchVm.AdminSearch.SubmittedTo)
    .Select(x => x.Table);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
mainTables = mainTables.Where(d =>
((d.n.CreatedDate == null && d.n.PlannedStartDate >= AdminSearchVm.AdminSearch.SubmittedFrom)
|| (d.n.CreatedDate != null && d.n.CreatedDate >= AdminSearchVm.AdminSearch.SubmittedFrom))

&& ((d.n.CreatedDate == null && d.n.PlannedStartDate <= AdminSearchVm.AdminSearch.SubmittedIo)
|| (d.n.CreatedDate != null && d.n.CreatedDate <= AdminSearchVm.AdminSearch.SubmittedIo)));
```

or you can like this

```
mainTables = mainTables.Where(d =>
(d.n.CreatedDate == null 
&& d.n.PlannedStartDate >= AdminSearchVm.AdminSearch.SubmittedFrom
&& d.n.PlannedStartDate <= AdminSearchVm.AdminSearch.SubmittedTo)
||                              
(d.n.CreatedDate != null 
&& d.n.CreatedDate >= AdminSearchVm.AdminSearch.SubmittedFrom
&& d.n.CreatedDate <= AdminSearchVm.AdminSearch.SubmittedIo));
```